# Python "R Cut" function

Tags: python, intervals

I am wondering if there is a function in Python already written for the goal that I describe later. If not, what would be the easiest way to implement. My code is attached.

Say I have a range from 1 to 999999999. Given a list of numbers like this:

```
[9, 44, 99]
```

It would return

```
[(1,9), (10,44), (45,99), (100, 999999999)]
```

If the number which are the limits are included in the input numbers, it should handle that also. 
Say input is

```
[1, 9, 44, 999999999]
```

The return should be:

```
[(1,9), (10,44), (45, 999999999)]
```

I could write a for loop comparing with a few conditional statement but wondering if there is a more 'smart way'.

Some data massage that might be helpful:

```
points = [1, 9, 44, 99]
points = sorted(list(set(points + [1, 999999999])))
```

***UPDATED INFO:
FINAL CREDITS GIVEN TO alecxe, thanks for your inspiring list comprehension solution***

```
l = sorted(list(set(points + [1, 999999999])))
[(l[i] + int(i != 0), l[i + 1]) for i in xrange(len(l) - 1)]
```

You can put all that in one line but I think that is unnessary.

Comment: -1: did you want (45, 109) in your first example?  If your going to explain an algorithm with an example only, please make sure that example is correct before you post.

Comment: I am so sorry about the typo before, problem fixed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[pandas.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Example

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ---> [A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D,E,E]
```

R:

```
x  <- seq(1,10,1)
cut(x, breaks = seq(0,10,2), labels = c('A','B','C','D','E'))
```

Python:

```
import pandas
x = range(1, 11, 1)
pandas.cut(x, bins=range(0, 12, 2), labels=['A','B','C','D','E'])
```

Comment: This is just so concise and beautiful <3.

Comment: Thank you! Who says that the stackoverflow community isn't friendly ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def myCut(low, high, points):
    answer = []
    curr = low
    for point in points:
        answer.append((curr, point))
        curr = point + 1
    answer.append((curr, high))
    return answer

>>> low = 1
>>> high = 999999999
>>> points = [9, 44, 109]
>>> myCut(low, high, points)
[(1, 9), (10, 44), (45, 109), (110, 999999999)]
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538981/198633) and the discussions that followed, here's a solution in fewer lines, with `itertools`. This uses `itertools.chain` and `itertools.izip` (in python2.7; `zip` in python3.x) to reduce the time and space complexities arising from adding lists, sorting and setifying. Note that the solution assumes that the input list is already sorted, failing which, erroneous results will be produced

```
cuts = [(i+1, j) for i,j in itertools.izip(itertools.chain([0], myList), itertools.chain(myList, [999999999]))]

>>> import itertools
>>> myList = [9, 44, 99]
>>> [(i+1, j) for i,j in itertools.izip(itertools.chain([0], myList), itertools.
chain(myList, [999999999]))]
[(1, 9), (10, 44), (45, 99), (100, 999999999)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this approach is the best one:

```
>>> l = [1, 9, 44, 999999999]
>>> [(l[i] + int(i != 0), l[i + 1]) for i in xrange(len(l) - 1)]
[(1, 9), (10, 44), (45, 999999999)]
```

If you are on python 3, replace `xrange` with `range`.

Note, that for your first example to work, you'll need to prepend and append your boundaries:

```
>>> l = [9, 44, 109]
>>> low, high = 1, 999999999
>>> l = [low] + l + [high]
>>> [(l[i] + int(i != 0), l[i + 1]) for i in xrange(len(l) - 1)]
[(1, 9), (10, 44), (45, 109), (110, 999999999)]
```

Comment: Clever! But note that you'll need to prepend the `1` to `l` and append the `999999999` to it as a preprocessing step

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I feel like it's not that efficient to make a list like `[low] + l + [high]`, like your solution more.

Comment: have you considered `l.insert(0, low); l.append(high)`? (the insert might still be O(n)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget yeah, I think this is almost the same, in terms of complexity..long story short, strictly speaking, the solution would be ok to use if the list is not very large or it doesn't seriously affects overall performance.

Comment: @alecxe this would make those concerns goes away regardless of how ugly the list might look like, but I am not quite sure of how much extra resource it would take:  l = sorted(list(set(points + [1, 999999999])))

Comment: @B.Mr.W. interesting option, thanks for sharing! But those conversions and sorting look like an overhead..not sure if it better than this ugly prepend and append :)

Comment: @B.Mr.W.: that's ~4n space and ~nlogn+2n time (so about O(nlogn) time in all plus a lot of space) for just those conversions and the sorting! Check out the edit to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18538978/198633) with a more efficient implementation of your idea

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the code from the answers with timeit, it looks like inspectorG4dget's solution performs way better (especially with Python 3) even though I left out the addition of the low and high value in the list comprehension solution:

```
ls = [9, 44, 109, 200, 567, 894, 6879, 29823]

def f1(low, high, points):
    answer = []
    curr = low
    for point in points:
        answer.append((curr, point))
        curr = point + 1
    answer.append((curr, high))
    return answer

def f2(low, high, l):
    a = [(l[i] + int(i != 0), l[i + 1]) for i in range(len(l) - 1)]
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    print(timeit.timeit("f1(1, 99999999, ls)", setup="from __main__ import f1, ls"))
    print(timeit.timeit("f2(1, 99999999, ls)", setup="from __main__ import f2, ls"))
```

Results (py3 on my netbook):

```
3.2064807919996383
8.850830605999363
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How about comparing the beauty of code? :)