# Is there a more efficient way to calculate a population's distribution of age and sex?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was working on a data analysis problem, trying to figure out if the distribution of the population of a dataset was representative of the US population. I also wanted to figure out a way to do this that is relatively simple, hopefully without using additional libraries, but also more compact than my solution.

I figured a dictionary would be the easiest way to understand the data, so I created one, with empty values for every age-sex key that I needed (since the data only spanned the ages 18-64). The code I used can be seen below, I ended up using a lot of elif statements to check and add one to the value of the corresponding key, but certain there has to be a smaller solution to this.

```
def age_sex_sort(self):
    self.age_sex_dictionary = {
        "18 to 19, Male": 0,
        "18 to 19, Female": 0,
        "20 to 24, Male": 0,
        "20 to 24, Female": 0,
        "25 to 29, Male": 0,
        "25 to 29, Female": 0,
        "30 to 34, Male": 0,
        "30 to 34, Female": 0,
        "35 to 39, Male": 0,
        "35 to 39, Female": 0,
        "40 to 44, Male": 0,
        "40 to 44, Female": 0,
        "45 to 49, Male": 0,
        "45 to 49, Female": 0,
        "50 to 54, Male": 0,
        "50 to 54, Female": 0,
        "55 to 59, Male": 0,
        "55 to 59, Female": 0,
        "60 to 64, Male": 0,
        "60 to 64, Female": 0}
    for (age, sex) in zip(self.patients_ages, self.patients_sexes):
        if sex == "male":
            if int(age) < 20:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["18 to 19, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 25:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["20 to 24, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 30:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["25 to 29, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 35:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["30 to 34, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 40:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["35 to 39, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 45:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["40 to 44, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 50:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["45 to 49, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 55:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["50 to 54, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 60:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["55 to 59, Male"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 65:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["60 to 64, Male"] += 1
        else:
            if int(age) < 20:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["18 to 19, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 25:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["20 to 24, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 30:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["25 to 29, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 35:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["30 to 34, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 40:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["35 to 39, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 45:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["40 to 44, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 50:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["45 to 49, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 55:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["50 to 54, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 60:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["55 to 59, Female"] += 1
            elif int(age) < 65:
                self.age_sex_dictionary["60 to 64, Female"] += 1
    return self.age_sex_dictionary
```

Comment: *"without using additional libraries"* -- Why not? I'm pretty sure with Pandas, you could accomplish this in like two lines.

Comment: integer division age / 5 will give you a number from 3 to 12 so that result -3 could be an array entry which maps to 18-19, 20-24....60-64 so that may remove the need for the if cases if you instead use an array and map it afterwards

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) if you want tips.

Comment: OK, not two lines, but I was able to do it in like four lines with Pandas, plus like 10 lines of setup.

Comment: "A more efficient way" is completely open-ended. Questions should be amenable to canonically correct answers.

Comment: There are some hints here to "cut" a list of numbers at specific points (like cut() in R) : https://stackoverflow.com/q/18538920/10466714. Could you provide a working example of your code (with a sample of your data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your life easier by rounding age down to 5:

```
from collections import Counter

def round(age):
    return age // 5 * 5

sex_age = Counter()
for (age, sex) in zip(patients_ages, patients_sexes):
    age = round(age)
    sex_age[f"{age} to {age+4}, {sex.capitalize()}"] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple 2-dimensional array:

```
def age_sex_sort(self):
    age_array = [[0]*20,[0]*20]
    for age, sex in zip(self.patients_ages, self.patients_sexes):
        age_array[sex=="male"][age//5] += 1

    return age_array

# Now:
#   age_array[0][3] has females 18 to 19
#   age_array[1][3] has males 18 to 19
#   age_array[0][4] has females 20 to 24
#   age_array[1][4] has males 20 to 24
# etc
```

This makes data analysis a lot easier than trying to ply through your dictionary.

Comment: An unnested dictionary with tuples as keys would work too.